# How do you access THEN and ELSE tag in TYPO3Fluid AbstractViewHelper?

Tags: php, typo3, fluid, typo3-9.x

There is a new AbstractViewHelper in TYPO3 (TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper) and I try to implement a very simple InArrayViewHelper to my project with that.

The problem is you should use `render()` if you like to access `then` or `else` sub tags according to https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/master/en-us/8-Fluid/8-developing-a-custom-viewhelper.html#renderstatic-method

So I do something like

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Project\ViewHelpers;

use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\Traits\CompileWithRenderStatic;
use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper;

class InArrayViewHelper extends AbstractViewHelper {

    //use CompileWithRenderStatic;

    public function initializeArguments() {
        $this->registerArgument('haystack', 'mixed', 'View helper haystack ', TRUE);
        $this->registerArgument('needle', 'string', 'View helper needle', TRUE);
    }

    public function render() {  
        $needle = $this->arguments['needle'];
        $haystack = $this->arguments['haystack'];
        if(!is_array($haystack)) { 
            return $this->renderElseChild();
        }
        if(in_array($needle, $haystack)) {
            return $this->renderThenChild();
        } else {
            return $this->renderElseChild();
        }  
    }

}
```

Well but they removed `renderThenChild` and `renderElseChild` in there. What is the right way to do so. Can I do it without using \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractConditionViewHelper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: if you want your ViewHelper to be a condition ViewHelper you should be subclassing `TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractConditionViewHelper`, not `TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper`. The former contains a collection of assistance methods, e.g. `renderThenChild` (which renders either the `f:then` node or returns the `then` argument, whichever is present).

Second: access to the *tags* (as opposed to a closure which renders either the tag or the compiled execution) can only happen while the template is not yet compiled, and can be achieved through overriding `public static function postParseEvent` which receives the `ViewHelperNode` which allows you to read the child nodes with `getChildNodes` and/or add additional child nodes through `addChildNode`.

Implementations based on `TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper` and using manually registered `then` and `else` arguments can also work, but will not support child nodes like `f:then` without replicating almost all of the assistance methods from `TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractConditionViewHelper`.

So the answer is: yes, you can do it without `AbstractConditionViewHelper` - but you shouldn't.

Comment: For all later incoming coders out there: Have a look at the example in the `news` extension where you have a complete example that works perfectly: https://github.com/georgringer/news/blob/master/Classes/ViewHelpers/IfIsActiveViewHelper.php